# How to find out where sbt resolves dependencies from?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using sbt `0.12 RC2`.

My project has a bunch of library dependencies, and some of these trigger other dependencies.  Some of these dependencies are unmanaged (in `lib/`), some are in my local `.ivy2` repository, some are found in various remote repositories.

I'm looking for an `sbt update-verbose` or similar that will tell me exactly where sbt found each JAR file when it says:

```
[info] Resolving com.nicta#sbt-scoobi;0.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.opennlp#opennlp-maxent;3.0.1-incubating ...
[info] Resolving jwnl#jwnl;1.3.3 ...
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111989/how-to-find-out-which-dependency-caused-a-particular-library-to-be-downloaded

Answer (score 5):

`sbt`generates a very extensive report on how exactly the dependencies were resolved in `target/resolution-cache/reports`. Open one of the `.xml` files in a web browser, and you should see all the detail you need.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this applies to sbt 0.12.x, but in 0.13.x, if you can find where your library lives in in the `~/.ivy/cache/...` directory structure, the library's parent directory has a file named `ivydata-x.y.z.properties` which contains the URL where it found the dependency.

For example, if you cache for `akka-streams` looks like this:

```
.ivy2
└── cache
    └── com.typesafe.akka
        └── akka-stream_2.11
            ├── docs
            │   └── akka-stream_2.11-2.4.14-javadoc.jar
            ├── jars
            │   └── akka-stream_2.11-2.4.14.jar
            └── srcs
                └── akka-stream_2.11-2.4.14-sources.jar
```

you should find a file like this, containing download URL:

```
.ivy2
└── cache
    └── com.typesafe.akka
        └── akka-stream_2.11
            └──ivydata-2.4.14.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `show compile:dependency-classpath` to show where the depedencies are

Comment: That doesn't give me what I'm looking for. It just lists the Java classpath.  I'd like to know, e.g. for a dependency `com.nicta#sbt-scoobi;0.0.1`, where it actually came from (e.g. the unmanaged `lib/` directory, the local `~/.ivy2` repository, the local `~/.m2` repository, a specific remote Ivy2 or Maven repository, etc.).

Comment: `Attributed(/Users/guillaume/.ivy2/cache/org.specs2/specs2_2.9.1/jars/specs2_2.9.1-1.11.jar)` so this one is from `~/.ivy2`

Comment: No, that's the cache.  That's not the source.  It doesn't tell you whether it originated locally or remotely, or where from.

Answer (score 0):

The details of the last task can be recalled by running **last**

Details and more info here:

[Configure and use logging](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Howto/logging.html)